# R: Dataframe Manipulation (group_by/aggregate)

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, aggregate, data-manipulation

I have the following data frame as shown below

| Code | Type | Fee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | JSON | 10 |
| AA | R | 20 |
| AA | R | 10 |
| DD | PYTHON | 30 |
| DD | JSON | 15 |
| ZZ | R | 50 |
| ZZ | PYTHON | 60 |
| ZZ | PYTHON | 10 |

```
code = c(rep("AA",3), rep("DD",2), rep("ZZ",3))
Type = c("JSON", "R", "R", "PYTHON", "JSON", "R", "PYTHON", "PYTHON")
Fee = c(10,20,10,30,15,50,60,10)
Price = as.data.frame(cbind(code, Type, Fee)); Price$Fee = as.integer(as.character(Price$Fee))
```

I would like to change the data frame to the one shown below with the Fee summed up accordingly

|  | JSON | R | PYTHON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 10 | 30 | 0 |
| DD | 15 | 0 | 30 |
| ZZ | 0 | 50 | 70 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use `Price = data.frame(code, Type, Fee)` to construct the dataframe, you would not need `Price$Fee = as.integer(as.character(Price$Fee))`

Comment: FYI there are mechanisms in place for when questions have already been asked other than deleting the content of the question, which is why I've rolled back your edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We turn the data.frame from long to wide, the id_cols is the `code` (since it is in the rows), the names of columns are taken from the `Type` column, and finally values are taken from `Fee`.

Since there are duplicates we need a method to sum values (for example ZZ python appears twice), we use the `sum` function.

Finally, we remove `NA`s and replace them with 0.

```
 library(tidyvesre) 

> new_dat <- Price %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = code, names_from = Type, 
                                   values_from = Fee, values_fn = sum, values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  code   JSON     R PYTHON
  <chr> <int> <int>  <int>
1 AA       10    30      0
2 DD       15     0     30
3 ZZ        0    50     70
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr` -

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(Price, names_from = Type, values_from = Fee, 
                   values_fn = sum, values_fill = 0)

#  code   JSON     R PYTHON
#  <chr> <int> <int>  <int>
#1 AA       10    30      0
#2 DD       15     0     30
#3 ZZ        0    50     70
```

And with `data.table` `dcast` -

```
library(data.table)

dcast(setDT(Price), Type ~ code, value.var = 'Fee', fun.aggregate = sum)
```